# Access @ApiOperation attributes in Swagger ApiAuthorizationFilter

Tags: java, scala, jax-rs, swagger

I have a Jax-RS webservice, which I document using Swagger. Now I want to check the parameters from the @ApiOperation annotation of each method to do some filtering.

```
@GET
@ApiOperation(value = "a description", response = String.class, hidden=true)
public static Response get(){}
```

I created an ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl according to this example:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/java-jaxrs/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/util/ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl.java#L60

I overwrote the isOperationAllowed method:

```
public boolean isOperationAllowed(Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map<String, List<String>> params, Map<String, String> cookies, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {

       System.out.println("params: "+params.keySet()); //<--params is empty
}
```

Now, when I am trying to access params, it is empty.
On the opposite, I can print the parameters from operation.parameters() but I also can't access them, as I get a Scala list with parameters.

The filter in general is access when starting the Swagger-UI, so it seems to be correctly passed in my web.xml.

Is this a silly mistake from my side, or how will I be able to access the parameters?

As a workaround I also wouldn't mind to access parameters from @ApiModelProperty annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample code to access the Scala parameters inside the isOperationAllowed method:

```
@Override
public boolean isOperationAllowed( Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map< String , List< String >> params, Map< String , String > cookies, Map< String , List< String >> headers ) {

    scala.collection.immutable.List< Parameter > paramList = operation.parameters();

    for ( int i = 0; i < paramList.length(); i++ ) {

        Parameter myparam = paramList.apply( i );

        if ( myparam.paramAccess().isDefined() && myparam.paramAccess().get().equals( "private" ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My REST class is annotated like this:

```
@POST
@ApiOperation( value = "create" )
@ApiImplicitParam( access = "private" )
public Response create( ... ) { ... }
```

Comment: Thats something I was looking for. Thanks. But I had to use it a bit different: @ApiImplicitParams(value = {@ApiImplicitParam(access ="")}).

Answer (score 0):

I think my question is a bit imprecise, so I will close it.
I made the mistake trying to access @ApiOperation attributes but reading the @ApiParams instead.

To clarify my actual need, I opened up a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868665/accessing-attribute-hidden-of-apioperation-annotation-in-swagger.